# $ still not defined after moving jQuery file to head

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cloud9-ide

I've explored reasonable remedies found here and elsewhere, but for for some reason cloud9 does not want to let me play with jQuery. I started with the "links at the bottom approach," got the `$ not defined please fix or add /*global $*/` error (even though my code was in `$(document).ready(function () {});` ), then moved everything up to the `<head>` tag so that there was no way my script could try to run before jQuery was loaded. Still, the same error. What gives?

Note I also tried reversing the order of the bootstrap and google jQuery links. Also, very new at front-end dev. Thx.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Bootstrap Links -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- style -->
        <style>
            .container-fluid {
                font-family: Serif, Helvetica;
                background-color: #8A2BE2;
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }

            #container-top {
                height: 75vh;
                margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
                background-color: #000000;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-size: 50px;
            }

            /* word-wrap added to ensure quote remained in container */
            .quote {
                font-family: Serif, Helvetica;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }

            /*
            .vertical-align {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;

            }
            */

        </style>
        <!-- scripts -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
```

Comment: Always jQuery before Bootstrap - you will see errors in the console if you don't do that.

Comment: Could be noconflict mode is running by default

Comment: I know you said you had already reversed them , but you definitely need to put jquery.min.js before bootstrap.min.js, as bootstrap requires jquery

Comment: Ok, reversed again, and nothing has changed. @Deckerz, what is noconflict mode? Anyone know why links at the bottom didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> got the $ not defined please fix or add /*global $*/ error (even
>   though my code was in $(document).ready(function () {}); )

It means something else removes `$` reference to jQuery. To avoid it in `document` ready handler, you can pass explicit alias:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
  // now '$' refers to jQuery inside ready handler even if '$' has been overwritten by other code
});
```

Comment: Your `$(document)` would need to be changed to `jQuery(document)` as `$` doesnt exist...

Comment: @Deckerz OP said it exists at time it is processed, otherwise it wouldn't said: `even though my code was in $(document).ready(function () {});` because the error would be different

Comment: He says `$ not defined please fix or add /*global $*/` which means $ doesnt exist

Comment: @Deckerz But from code inside ready handler, not from `$(document)`

Comment: That's interesting. It took care of the errors that appeared inside of the $(document).ready . . . function. I haven't seen this explanation elsewhere.

Comment: @A.Wolff ah i see, i misunderstood what he meant +1

Comment: This is an interesting answer, I wasn't aware that you could customize the jquery alias. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery references **always** need to be included **before** plugins that rely on it.

Here is the solution you provided in your question added as SO snippet so you can see for yourself that it **should** work when references are added in the correct order.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container-fluid").append("jquery is set up correctly");
});
```

```css
.container-fluid {
  font-family: Serif, Helvetica;
  background-color: #8A2BE2;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#container-top {
  height: 75vh;
  margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 50px;
}

/* word-wrap added to ensure quote remained in container */
.quote {
  font-family: Serif, Helvetica;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

/*
.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}
*/
```

```html
<!-- notice that jQuery reference has been added first !-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid"></div>
```

Comment: So, the errors are still showing in the margin of my IDE, but, yes, your message displays in the container. So, while I needed the correction RE: the ordering of links, this is more a cloud9 thing than anything else. Your example helped parse this out.

Comment: Glad it got you a little further